# Not able to execute Query in MariaDB using MySQL as Driver

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I am testing one simple program that is connecting to DB and fetch my_test table details.

I am getting exception as `java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin.`

stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin ''.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:923)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1715)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2412)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
        at TestRoot.main(TestRoot.java:19)
```

I am using Driver as MySQL.
My Database is mariadb-5.5.30.

```
      Connection con=null;
      Statement st=null;
      ResultSet rs=null;
      String firstName="";
      try
      {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

              con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_test","root","");
              st=con.createStatement() ;
              rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test") ;
              while(rs.next())
              {
                      firstName=rs.getString(2);
                      System.out.println(firstName);
              }

      }
      catch(Exception err)
      {
              System.out.println(err.toString());
      }
```

I knew Connection, ResultSet are not closed, but that cannot be the cause of issue I think.

Comment: you need change driver, (mysql 5.1.6 to 5.1.18) worked for my, or change hash pass mysql acount as Michael Laffargue says.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look here : https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-3935

> the issue occurs when the password set on the mysql.user table uses an
>   older format - of the form 7f84554057dd964b (which I believe is
>   'badpwd') rather than something like
>   *AAB3E285149C0135D51A520E1940DD3263DC008C which is the newer form.
>
> Resetting the password for the user record(s) as noted in MDEV-545
>   does solve the issue as it upgrades the password format in the tables.

---

From MariaDB documentation : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pam-authentication-plugin/

> Note: Windows does not use PAM, so the PAM authentication plugin does not work on Windows. However, one can use the Windows client to connect to a MariaDB server — on Linux or Solaris, for example — which does use the PAM authentication plugin. See this example.

From what I understand you should install it on linux (read the doc from the previous link)

Comment: I have 2 installation of MaraDB, one I have in my local and running on Windows and one on Linux. I changed my windows mariaDB password to one which is giving me error on Linux machine and it works fine. Also, Problem only happens while connecting problematically.

Comment: It could be version related, could you try an older version of MariaDB ?

Comment: I have the same version of MariaDB installed in both local(Windows) and test(Linux) Machine. it is working on Windows but issue is with Linux one, still I should try with another version of MariaDB on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by changing the jdbc driver. I used MariaDB jdbc driver:

(from the Spring configuration file)

Hope this will be helpful.